# A question about inflection point - do we need to check the 3rd derivative value?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Say a function is 3 times differentiable in some neighborhood
$(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ of the point $a$ (where $\delta \gt 0$).

There is a well-known theorem saying that if $f'''(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and $f''(a)=0$, and $f'''(a) \ne 0$, then the function $f$ has an inflection point at $x=a$. It is easily proved using Taylor's formula.

But what if we don't want to compute and check $f'''(a)$ just to save ourselves some calculations?

Say we already see that $f''(x) < 0$ when $x \lt a$ and $f''(x) > 0$ when $x \gt a$ (or vice versa).

Is this sufficient to claim that $f$ has inflection point at $x=a$? And if so, why? I mean based on which theorem...? Or... is it just easy to prove even though there is no specific theorem for this?

**NOTE**:
*The definition of inflection point $a$ (which I was given) is this one:

there's no neighborhood $K=(a-\theta, a+\theta)$ of $a$ such that the graph of

$f$ is **above or below** its tangent line (at the point $a$) in that (whole)

neighborhood $K$ i.e. an inflection point is a point where $f$ is neither

concave nor convex.*

Comment: Isn't that the definition of an inflection point ? For me, an inflection point is a point where $f'$ has an isolated extremum. So if $f''(x)<0$ when $x < a$ ans $f''(x)>0$ when $x>a$, then $a$ is an inflection point. The theorem you mention is quite different, because it gives you a condition to see that $a$ is an inflection point, just looking at the values of the derivatives at $a$ (and not in a neighborhood of $a$)

Comment: An inflection point is a point at which the derivative has a local extremum, so yes, in this case you have an inflection point, since $f'(a)$ is a local minimum.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe The definition of inflection point $a$ (which I was given) is this one: there's no neighborhood $K=(a-\theta, a+\theta)$ of $a$ such that the graph of $f$ is above/below its tangent in that (whole) neighborhood $K$ i.e. it is a point where $f$ is neither concave nor convex.

Comment: @Andrew yes, for example $g(x)=x^3$ for $a=0$

Comment: @Bernard Hm... is this a definition or theorem? I have a somewhat different definition.

Comment: For me, it's the geometric definition. Which definition do you have?

Comment: @Bernard It's in my comment.I put it in my question too.

Comment: @peter.petrov Try to prove that your definition is equivalent to our :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Now I got quite confused :) What is your definition (strictly put)? OK, I will try. So what you are saying is that the condition I give here is sufficient... almost by definition? In a way it's stronger than this theorem I cited?

Comment: I see. It's equivalent to the one I have: if you have a local extremum of $f'$ at $a$, $f''x)>0$  on one side of $a$ and $f''(x)<0$  on the other side if $x$ is close enough to $a$.

Comment: @peter.petrov Your definition in term of tangents is the same as mine ("an inflection point is a point where $f'$ has an isolated extremum"). The theorem you cited is quite different because it gives you a sufficient condition, just looking at what happens at $x=a$ (and not in a neighborhood), to say that $a$ is an inflection point

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks, I was able to prove that statement which I asked about using Taylor's formula. The proof turned out to be quite simple.